# Make Billing Phone required on Checkout Field Based on Shipping Method - Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to set the billing phone number required or not required based on the shipping method.

I have set the shipping method as an array and checked it from the session selected shipping method but it not working

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'fire_remove_billing_checkout_fields');

function fire_remove_billing_checkout_fields($fields) {
   
    global $woocommerce;
    $methods = array('flat_rate:2', 'flat_rate:3', 'flat_rate:17', 'flat_rate:20');// Set shipping method to hide the checkout field(s).
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];




    if(in_array($chosen_shipping, $methods)){

       $fields['billing']['billing_phone'][ 'required' ] = true;
    }else{
       $fields['billing']['billing_phone'][ 'required' ] = false;
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well for me. I've added my shipping rate IDs and it works as expected, however **refresh of the page is necessary**, because WooCommerce doesn't refresh the billing fields natively on `update_checkout` trigger.

You should either reload the page using Javascript/jQuery on `updated_checkout` event, or reload only the billing fields using AJAX like so:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'reload_billing_fields_on_updated_checkout' );
function reload_billing_fields_on_updated_checkout() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document.body).on('updated_checkout', () => {
            jQuery('.woocommerce-billing-fields').load(`${location.href} .woocommerce-billing-fields>*`, '');
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Keep in mind that it might take a short while for those fields to reload, so you might want to add some loading CSS classes, or maybe a spinner.